# Unload the system loaded module in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

If system has already installed modules, say "servicefabric", and while running my script I want to remove this module as it might be previous version. And I want to import my new latest servicefabric module. May I know how can be done this?

I tried this:

```
if(Get-Module -Name "ServiceFabric") 
{
    Remove-Module -Name "ServiceFabric"
}
```

But it's not removing the system installed service fabric module.

And the same module is getting listed from this below command

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "ServiceFabric"
```

when I tried again. So, I just want to remove the system loaded module.

Comment: Do you want to remove or to uninstall the module? `Remove-Module` just unloads the module.

Comment: I don't want to uninstall the module. I wanted to remove it from my current session and I just wanted to use my new latest service fabric module which I'm going to import it from my code.

Comment: `Get-Module -ListAvailable` lists the available modules, not the modules that are actually loaded. The latter is what `Get-Module` without `-ListAvailable` does.

Answer (score 1):

If the module is defined in an assembly, or if the module includes an assembly, then it's not possible to unload it. The cmdlet names will be removed but the assembly will stay in memory.

This isn't a Powershell issue - .Net doesn't allow unloading of assemblies. Instead you have to unload the AppDomain containing the assembly.

Comment: If I have to unload the AppDomain containing the assembly, then in that case, how can I unload it. After my work, can I load it AppDomain again.

Comment: I very much doubt you'll be able to unload the AppDomain as it belongs to Powershell, and trying to do so is going to probably affect the environment. Can you avoid loading the module in the first place?

Comment: Hmm....I have to place it on top, because I have to connect to cluster and then need to deploy the application/upgrade/overwrite. So, can I have any other option, saying loading my particular version of Service Fabric dll's and continue the deployment with powershell.

Comment: Can anybody help on this please. As I have to do this further.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try? Remove-Module -Name "ServiceFabric" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue. You don't need to check if the module is load. Just remove it if any found.

Comment: I have tried with the above one. When I execute it, it is not giving error. But, as I have to import new modules, and based on the imported modules what ever I written the code is not getting executed. When I don't import the new module what ever the error which I'm getting the same error I'm getting after importing the latest module as well. I have placed the Remove-Module code in top of the powershell script page.